# Foundation 5 - centering column only on small screen. How?

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

If I write

```
<div class="large-4 medium-4 small-6 small-centered columns">
```

then the column is centered on large, medium and small screens. Is there a way to have it centered only on a small screen, but on a large and medium screen they stay floated left?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div class="large-4 medium-4 small-6 small-centered medium-uncentered columns">
```

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html#centered-columns